# CF convention and GDAL projection

Tags: python, gdal, netcdf

I'm trying to create some NETCDF4 CF compliant files from some code that generates GDAL compatible files. I was wondering whether there is a simple translation from GDAL (or proj4) projection information and geotransform and what netcdf/CF expects.

I am using Python, GDAL (1.11.2), and the python NetCDF4 bindings, and it is safe to assume that I have an e.g. Proj4 string and a GDAL GeoTransform array available. The projections can range from the standard no projection WGS84 kind of data, to local a bunch of local, equal area types (e.g. UTM, or MODIS sinusoidal).